# Append a variable to a link in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, itunes

Currently I have this working code:

```
on run
set info to ""
tell application "System Events"
    set num to count (every process whose name is "iTunes")
end tell
if num > 0 then
    tell application "iTunes"
        if player state is playing then
            set albumName to (get album of current track)
        end if
    end tell
end if
return text 1 thru 10 of albumName
end run
```

if running iTunes and live albums are formatted correctly (YYYY-MM-DD) - this will bring back the date of a live album. I'd like to now take the result of "return text 1 thru 10 of albumName" and add it to this code:

```
tell application "Firefox" to activate
tell application "Firefox"
open location "http://someband.com/showID=" &  *[insert code for "text 1 thr 10 of albumName" variable]*
end tell
```

I know the "&" isn't correct but I thought that was the start. The way this should work is if I'm listening to "2013-03-12 Live on StackOverflow" I want the script to take "2013-03-12" and append it to my link so Firefox opens website address: "http://someband.com/showID=2013-03-12"

...make sense? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if application "iTunes" is not running then return

tell application "iTunes"
    if player state is playing then
        set albumName to (get album of current track)
    end if
end tell

set myText to text 1 thru 10 of albumName

-- Assuming Firefox is your default browser…
open location "http://someband.com/showID=" & myText
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't vote you up because I'm new but thank you so much that works! Have a wonderful day because you made mine!